# iOS Objective-C wrap text of UITextField in UIAlertView and dynamically adjust height based on content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have a `UIAlertView` with the `alertViewStyle` of `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`. I'm trying to find a way to make the `UITextField` of the `UIAlertView` adjust its height and wrap its text based on its content as the user types.

To be quite honest, I haven't the slightest clue how to do this.

Here is some of my code:

```
-(void)updateTicket:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *sndr = (UIButton*)sender;
    int index = sndr.tag;

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    [alert setTag:-7];
    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Update Ticket #%i", [ticketIDs[index] intValue]]];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert textFieldAtIndex:0].placeholder = @"Note";
    [alert textFieldAtIndex:0].tag = index;
    [alert textFieldAtIndex:0].autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
    [alert textFieldAtIndex:0].autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
    [alert textFieldAtIndex:0].autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    [alert setCancelButtonIndex:0];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Its not possible for UITextField, because textfield only take 1 line text. So u have to create custom alert with UITextView

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a `UITextField` with multiple lines and dynamic height.

To achieve this please create a custom alert and add a `UITextView` as `UITextView`can have multiple lines. Override the  *textViewDidChange:* and calculate the size of the text in the textview with 
*sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:*. It will return the `CGSize` based on the height adjust the height of the `UITextView` and the alert.

Thanks