# UIAlertController message getting truncated to one line

Tags: swift, user-interface, uialertcontroller

In my app, while presenting the `UIAlertController` it's truncating the message to one line. How to make it display to show full text with word wrap.

[image: screenshot]

Here is my code

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message:"Long text"  , 
preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert) 

let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: 
UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)  

alert.addAction(okAction)

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: A similar question has been asked, so this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941515/ios-objective-c-wrap-text-of-uitextfield-in-uialertview-and-dynamically-adjust-h

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIActionSheet/UIAlertController multiline text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215654/uiactionsheet-uialertcontroller-multiline-text)

Comment: Yeah i have tried using that still last few characters are getting truncated @JonSnow

Comment: Apple doesn't recommended to use a long text alerts. It's must be short and readable.

Comment: Try ***"\n***" to split lines [For Refrence Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571315/how-to-make-a-multiple-line-left-aligned-uialertview)

Answer (score 11):

I found the issue.I was overriding the UILabel class in my code. when i have removed the code now it's working fine.

Comment: Even I am having the same issue. You were override UILabel Property of which Controller?

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale I have overridden the `UILable` class to add some custom functionality that caused this issue. once commented that it's working fine

Comment: @Kalikanth040494 How can I find that?

Comment: @Hilaj  I have added some extra custom function using extensions.

Comment: I found my issue, for padding I am actually using one extension, which makes the issue in my case

Comment: @Hilaj Great! nice to hear that you have traced your issue.

Comment: Thanks! Never thought this was causing the issue as i was not using the extension

Comment: @Hilaj can you share that piece of code I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 8):

I was also facing the same problem from the last few days but finally found the solution.
I removed "padding with UIEdgeInsets" code, it's working fine.

Removed below code

```
extension UILabel {

    public var padding: UIEdgeInsets? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.padding) as? UIEdgeInsets
        }
        set {
            if let newValue = newValue {
                objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.padding, newValue as UIEdgeInsets, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UIAlertviewController.
Hope it will help!!!

Answer (score 2):

Since Swift 4 you can use multi-line strings: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-create-multi-line-string-literals

Example:

```
let longString = """
When you write a string that spans multiple
lines make sure you start its content on a
line all of its own, and end it with three
quotes also on a line of their own.
Multi-line strings also let you write "quote marks"
freely inside your strings, which is great!
"""
```

So, your code would be:

```
let longTextMessage = """
When you write a string that spans multiple
lines make sure you start its content on a
line all of its own, and end it with three
quotes also on a line of their own.
Multi-line strings also let you write "quote marks"
freely inside your strings, which is great!
"""

let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message:longTextMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert) 

let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: 
UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)  

alert.addAction(okAction)

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

LE: I used your code with a long text message like:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message:"Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text ",
                                      preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:
            UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(okAction)

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Nothing gets truncated.. there's something else that is messing with your alertController.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Yeah i got it. The messages which i'm showing are dynamic comes from server.

Comment: OK, but I used your code and the issue doesn't appear, no message gets truncated. You must do something different... see my edit above.

Comment: Thanks i got the issue. I was overriding the UILabel property that is why this strange behaviour happened. I removed the code now it's working fine

Answer (score -1):

In your string, you can manually add multiple lines with "\n"

```
let string = "This is \na string with \nmultiple lines"
```

should give you e.g. an string with total 3 lines.

Comment: But i'm displaying dynamic message which may consist of one line or two lines

Comment: Ah okay, you could count the characters then and insert an \n after each n characters. But that would not be that pretty, i think there is a better solution for that.

Comment: yes i have done that but if the nth character is not space it is dividing the single charecter. I don't know why the UIAlertController behaviour changed.

Comment: Yeah i didnt think of that, you could additionally check for a space and insert the \n after the space. Where do you get your dynamic message from?

Comment: from server while performing the URLSessionRequest. Can you please put me the code that how can i do that. Thanks in advance

Comment: `let string = "..."
//stringSplitBySpace is an array
let stringSplitBySpace = string.components(separatedBy: " ")

for word in stringSplitBySpace {
    if word.length > 10 { //if the word has more than 10 characters
         word = word += "\n"
    }
}

var resultString = ""

for word in stringSplitBySpace {
   resultString = resultString + word
}
`
this is just an idea, im not sure if it really works. And its possible that there are some syntax errors.

Comment: i think if string contains two side by side words greater than 10 characters . it breaks into line then it'll not be presentable right

Comment: i dont know if there is a limit for characters or how it is represented then